# I have an issue with returning an array from a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The program compiles but it gives the following error:

> Two
>   One
>   Three
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>   at testingN.printArray(testingN.java:19)
>   at testingN.main(testingN.java:10)

I am really new into Java ( and programming ) and I'm stuck with this.

```
public class testingN 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] names = new String[3];
        names[0] = "Two";
        names[1] = "One";
        names[2] = "Three";
        printArray(names);
    }
    public static String printArray(String[] data) 
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
          System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
        return data[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `return data[i];` is using index 3, because `i` is incremented before the loop exits.

Comment: Like @jonhopkins said, if you want to return the last element of the array you should  `return data[i-1];`. That said, a method that prints should be declared as `void` (not return anything). If you want to implement another functionality you should do it somewhere else...

Comment: Do you really need to return anything? It seems that you could just make the method `void` and take out the return statement.

Comment: Could you please implement a simple functionality somewhere else (new class or ?) for me just to see an example because I am really getting confused? :( I do not want to use void method, but a return method !

Comment: To be honest, what I really need to do is to create an array of numbers (input with scanner) and given this array I want to return another array with new numbers(I have to use some formula in the return method to convert the numbers)

Comment: @ItsoIvanov, if you're trying to create a new array based on the input array, in your method you should have something like `String[] /* or int[] */ newData = new String[data.length]; /* your formula code here */ return newData;`. Note that you aren't returning a specific element in the array, rather you need to return the entire array. Because of this, you will also need to change the return type of your method.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the way a `for` loop works.

```
for (*initialization*; *some boolean condition*; *action to perform each loop*) {
    //...
}
```

A for loop works as follows:

1. It begins by running the code in the initialization section. In your case, it sets `i = 0`
2. It runs the contents of the loop
3. It performs the action. In your case `i++`.
4. It checks the boolean condition. If it is true, it goes to step 2. Otherwise it exits the loop. In your case the condition is `i < data.length`.

Since step 3 happens before the condition is checked, your `i` value is going to be 1 larger than the array size -1. That is, it will be the index exactly one larger than the last index of the array. So `return data[i];` gives you an out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class testingN 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] names = new String[3];
        names[0] = "Two";
        names[1] = "One";
        names[2] = "Three";
        printArray(names);
    }
    public static void printArray(String[] data) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
          System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```